# How to open a webpage in a new window(Pop up)

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am designing a webpage in which I want that when a user click on link a popup (new window) will open with a linked webpage.
My code looks like below

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function win(add,w,h)
{
window.open(add,"","width="+w+",height="+h+",location=0,directories=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=5,left=5");
window.location.reload();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Click to open link in new window</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="Menu">Account Master</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" value="new.htm" onclick="win(this.value,600,450)">New</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="mod.html" onclick="win(this.value,600,500)" >Modify</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="del.html" onclick="win(this.value,600,500)">Delete</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" value="view.html" onclick="win(this.value,600,500)">View</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

In Firefox on clicking the link a popup appear but no link open(means it open only blank page) and in IE popup appear with link(/undefined) not the link provided link.
I am unable to detect what is the error.

Comment: Have you tried using <a href="/path/to/file" target="_blank">Link</a>

Comment: target='_blank' is for open in new tab. He want in new window you must have to read it. I don't know much more about these but can you see these link ....http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

Comment: <a href="/path/to/file" target="_blank">Link</a> will open the link in another tab but I want to open in another window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function win(add,w,h)
{

window.open(add,"","width="+w+",height="+h+",location=0,directories=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=5,left=5");
window.location.reload();
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Click to open link in new window</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="Menu">Account Master</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="new.htm" value="new.htm" target="_blank" onclick="win(this.href,600,450)">New</a></li>
      <li><a href="mod.html" value="mod.html" target="_blank" onclick="win(this.href,600,500)" >Modify</a></li>
      <li><a href="del.html" value="del.html" target="_blank" onclick="win(this.href,600,500)">Delete</a></li>
      <li><a href="view.html" value="view.html" target="_blank" onclick="win(this.href,600,500)">View</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: but in your case, both window open the same page... i want that link should open only in new window not in current window...   okay i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not a link opens in a tab or window is determined by the user's browsers settings. You may want to rethink your end-solution.

Instead of displaying your linked page in a "new window/tab", try firing a modal. Here are some nifty modal effects that are easy to implement 
http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Answer (score 0):

use this property of anchor tag target="_blank"

```
<a target="_blank" href="link.html">Link</a>
```

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="link.html">Link</a> will open the link in another tab but I want to open in another window